# CRM 2011 : Unable to read [Object Object] returned in Success of RetrieveMultipleRecords

Tags: jquery, json, dynamics-crm-2011, odata

I'm using the jQuery 1.4.1, JSON 2 and SDK.JQuery.js( which is a wrapper for REST DataOperation provided in CRM SDK). While, using SDK.JQquery.RetrieveMultipleRecords function, I'm unable to read the Success response. For elaboration purpose, I explain below through the alert function.

BTW, code is executing correctly and giving 3 records which is correct too.

Code is as follows:-

```
SDK.JQuery.retrieveMultipleRecords(    
   "Contact",    
   "$select=FullName,ContactId&$filter=zk_cdn eq 'zk007'",    
   function(results) {    
   ////TODO: How to read results?    
   //If I use alert(results) it give the output as [object Object],[object Object],[object Object]    
   //If I use alert(results[0]) it give the output as [object Object]    
   //If I use alert(results[0].FullName) it give the output as unidentified    
   },    
   errorHandler,    
   function() {//OnComplete handler }    
   );

function errorHandler(error) {    
   alert(error.message);    
}
```

Looking forward to hear from you. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Debug. Put a breakpoint in the success function and see exactly what you have in results[0].

Answer (score 0):

You can access the set of all available attributes to that object by *attributes*. Or, you can go:

```javascript
var info = "";
for(attribute in myObject)
  info += "\n" + attribute;
```

Or something like that. Not in fron of a computer right now.

Comment: @Zohaib If your question got resolved, you should mark one of the replies as an answer (and vote it up if you like it). Otherwise, please elaborate on what's missing. :)